# Downloading data from Oracle DB and exporting to csv file

Tags: python, database, oracle

I have a connection to some Oracle data base and trying to export the data to a csv file. Below is my Python code -

```
import jpype
import jaydebeapi
import csv

# Assuming I already have established a connection -
# Connection variable is Conn

Curs = Conn.cursor()
Curs.execute("select * from Table")
Data = list(Curs.fetchall())

with open("mycsvfile.csv", "wb") as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, Data[0].keys())
    w.writerow(dict((fn,fn) for fn in Data[0].keys()))
    w.writerows(Data)
```

But when I ran above code, I got error as -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Could you please help me to find a way out?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this code to create a csv file using Python ( in my case with headers ). I think you should try `cx_Oracle` , for me it is the best way to interact with Oracle databases from Python.

```
import os
import sys
import cx_Oracle 

db = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@host:port/service_name')
SQL = "select column1 , column2 , .... , columnn from table"
print(SQL)
cursor = db.cursor()
f = open("C:\myfile.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
r = cursor.execute(SQL)

#this takes the column names
col_names = [row[0] for row in cursor.description]

writer.writerow(col_names)

for row in cursor:
   writer.writerow(row)
f.close()
```

Comment: WIth this code, I am getting error as - cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "dlopen(libclntsh.dylib, 1): image not found". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help

Comment: probably you don't have the right instant client version installed in your laptop

Comment: Commonly I see CSV being used to dump a large number of rows, so using the cursor.arraysize and cursor.prefetchrows settings could improve performance, see [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate csv using sqlplus or SQLcl:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/generating-HTML-reports-from-SQL-Plus.html

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sqlcl-format-query-results-with-the-set-sqlformat-command

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/a-quick-4-1-trick-set-sqlformat/

Comment: Thanks. But, I wanted to have some method to directly export data as CSV from my Python workspace.

Comment: For future readers using SQL*Plus, also see [Fast Generation of CSV and JSON from Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database).